# How to enable sorting only for one column in JQUERY Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im trying to enable sorting based on one column only in a datatable. but its not working. This is the way I tried

```
var myTable = $("#tbl_main").dataTable({
    "dom": "<'tableinfobar'i><'tablesearchbox'f><'tablestarfilter'><'tablebody't>S<'tablelength'l><'tablepaging'p>",
    "ordering": false,
    "columnDefs": [{"targets": [0, 6],"searchable": false}, {"targets":2, "type":"html-num","orderable":true}],
    "lengthMenu": [
        [10, 20, 50, 100, 500, -1],
        [10, 20, 50, 100, 500, "All"]
    ]
}).show();
```

Here I need to enable sorting only for second column only and tried that in **columnDefs**

Comment: try something like `"ordering":true
 "columnDefs": [
           { aTargets: [ '_all' ], bSortable: false },
           
           { aTargets: [ 1 ], bSortable: true }
        ]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

add class `no-sort` to all the `<th>` except the column which you want to sort.. kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/24zztcL9/

I have enabled sort only for 2nd column "Position"

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="no-sort">Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th class="no-sort">Office</th>
                <th class="no-sort">Age</th>
                <th class="no-sort">Start date</th>
                <th class="no-sort">Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
     </table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({

    "ordering": true,
    columnDefs: [{
      orderable: false,
      targets: "no-sort"
    }]

  });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Rather than using `columnDefs` I prefer using `columns` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "columns":[
            {
                "sortable": false
            },
            {
                "sortable": true
            },
            {
                "sortable": false
            },
            {
                "sortable": false
            },
            {
                "sortable": false
            },
            {
                "sortable": false
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/24zztcL9/2/)

Either approach works, I just prefer the granular control of the `columns` array.

Answer (score 2):

For me the Accepted answer did not work

because **in my table all `<th>` has same class and i can't add another class to `<th>` and also can not remove default class of `<th>`,**

My table's structure is as below:

```
       <table id="example" class="mt-table" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="mt-head">Name</th>
                    <th class="mt-head">Position</th>
                    <th class="mt-head">Office</th>
                    <th class="mt-head">Age</th>
                    <th class="mt-head">Start date</th>
                    <th class="mt-head">Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>Hari</td>
               <td>Senior Engineer</td>
               <td>Ahmedabad</td>
               <td>20</td>
               <td>11/02/2019</td>
               <td>50,000</td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
```

Now i also want to enable sort option for `Position` column only.

what i have done is as below:

In my `<script>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({

    "ordering": true,
    columnDefs: [
    {
        "orderable": true,
        "targets": 1,
    },
    {
      orderable: false,
      targets: "mt-head"
    }]

  });
});
```

Now only **Position** column will be orderable and all others will be not.

*So the rule is to put the **column first of all which you want to sort** in `columnDefs` as above example after it you can **put class selector to disable sorting** on all other columns.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
       $("#dgUsers").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("#dgUsers").find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
           "aoColumnDefs": [
             { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4, 5, 6 ] }
           ] }
       );
   });
```

Try This...

> 4, 5, 6 are column numbers starting with 0.