# DataTable: Custom Sorting on date inside td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, datatables

I have a JQuery [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) and it is working well but on particular column the sorting is not working as i want.

Into that column there are some different type of values like **Date**, **Number** and **Text** like below:

[image]

I want to implement a custom sorting on the **Date** field.

Is there any buddy know how to implement that?

Is there any way to apply a Custom Sorting on particular `<span>` tag in `<td>`. I can apply a `<span>` tag around the Date.

Or

Into some another way to implement this type of sorting.

I have read too many articles but nothing found helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This link might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35882936/how-to-enable-sorting-only-for-one-column-in-jquery-datatable

Comment: @SorangwalaAbbasali: Thank you for your message but that is not helpful to me. (

Comment: This is what you need. With few edits, you can get your date sorted http://jsfiddle.net/rYtxh/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
$("#example").DataTable({
    columns:[
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null,
        {
            "render": function(d){
                return $("<span></span>",{
                    "text": d,
                    "data-date": d.match(/[0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{4}$/)[0]
                }).prop("outerHTML");
            },
            "type": "data-date"
        }, 
        null
    ]
});

jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "data-date-pre": function(a) {
        return parseInt(moment($(a).data("date"), "DD/MM/YYYY").format("X"), 10);
    },
    "data-date-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "data-date-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

Basically, we wrap the relevant data in a span with the date extracted and added as a data attribute. We then sort on that. Hope that helps. Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/Lfo6ohvz/) with similar data.